# Get response data without loop angular2 error

Tags: angular, angular-loopback

In my angular2 project I am trying to get the value of email id from the object array. There is only 1 object I don't want to use loop. So I am trying to get the value using

```
{{customers[0].customer_email}}
```

which doesn't work but below code work.

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let customer of customers">
        <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="{{customer.customer_email}}"></ion-input>         
    </ion-item>
```

Any idea how do I use it without loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the `ngFor` and index your customers response directly:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value="{{customers[0].customer_email}}"></ion-input>         
</ion-item>
```

If you get an `array out of bounds` exception (which is caused by trying to apply an indexer `[0]` to an array without any elements), apply an ngIf to your item to prevent it from rendering until the data is loaded:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="customers && customers.length">
    <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value="{{customers[0].customer_email}}"></ion-input>         
</ion-item>
```

Comment: `{{ customers && customers[0].customer_email }}` should also work fine

Comment: @unitario excellent point, although that will also cause an "Email" label to render before the data, which may or may not be the desired behavior, but you are absolutely correct, it is a viable alternative.  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidL what is array out of bounds ? can you explain. It seem your code is working perfectly.

Comment: @Santosh I've updated my answer with a quick explanation.

Comment: @DavidL without any element means custom directives ?

Comment: @Santosh no, if the array is empty, without any data in the array.

Comment: @Santosh you're welcome and unitario's approach wouldn't be my first choice, which is why I recommended a different approach in my answer.  And technically unitario's approach is incomplete since it would actually need to be `{{ customers && customers.length && customers[0].customer_email }}`.

Comment: @Santosh thats because the array exists but it's empty resulting in an out of bounds error. It can be extended like so: `{{ customers && customers.length != 0 && customers[0].customer_email }}`

Comment: Yes I agree. Thank you for the effort. Much appreciated.. :)

Comment: is it possible to store `customers && customers.length != 0 && customers[0]` them in a variable and use it with single code ?

Comment: That's really a new question but yes you can bind to a public string property and assign the value when your data is returned.

Comment: @Santosh if this issue is solved, you can mark the answer as accepted. If you have other questions, please ask a new question.